# PHP-ODBC Driver Install Issue

Tags: php, linux, pdo, odbc, centos7

I'm banging my head on the keyboard... :-(  I'm trying to install php-odbc so I can use the odbc_connect() functions that worked like a beauty on a WAMP install.

There seems to be a mass dependency rabbit hole and it won't let me install... I can't seem to figure out how to manually install the php-odbc that works with "pdo-5.6"

```
[root@panel /]# yum install php-odbc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * remi-safe: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-odbc.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7 for package: php-odbc-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-odbc-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7
           Installed: php-pdo-5.6.30-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.30-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Im on CentOS 7.3.1611 (Core) and PHP 5.6.30 using Sentora

Note this too:

```
[root@panel /]# yum install php-pdo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * remi-safe: repo1.sea.innoscale.net
Package matching php-pdo-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Installed: php-pdo-5.6.30-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)

You have installed **php-pdo** from **remi-php56**, so you need to install **php-odbc** from the same repository. As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/), simple way is to enable it permanently.

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
```

Having the repository enabled permanently will also allow you to take benefit of security update (latest version is 5.6.31).

Comment: You totally rock!  I was trying to do this manually and it just cascaded dependencies and I had trouble finding the versions needed.  This did it in 10 seconds.